# UnsupportedMediaTypeException RAML Mule

Tags: mule, raml, apikit

**Requirement** - 
*User will hit an URL and a CSV is downloaded on calling machine.*

**Implementation** 
Below is my RAML (1.0) definition

```
  /{format}:
    is: [ genericErrorResponsesCompliant ]
    get:
      description: Get/Download list of all ACTIVE accounts in a given format (CSV/JSON) default is JSON
      body:
        application/json:
      responses:    
        200: 
          body: 
            application/octet-stream:
        202:
          body:
            application/json:                  
        404:
          body:
            application/json:
              example: !include resources/json/example/error/error-resource-not-found-response-example.json
```

**ISSUE**:
When request are sent using -

1. *API-Console* to invoke the API, a CSV response is seen
2. *postman* - I get UnsupportedMediaTypeException in Mule Console
3. *postman* (when Content-Type application/json is passed) CSV output is seen in the response section
4. *browser* I get the error UnsupportedMediaTypeException

**Question** 
If i do not set the content-type then the API-Kit fails validation and an exception is sent. Is there a way where a default Content-Type is set as *application/json* and the end-user can access the url from the browser and the csv is downloaded?

I should be able to overcome Exception thrown by API-Kit

If you need any more information let me know, but I am struggling to get this done. Any help will be appreciated.

**Exception**
    Root Exception stack trace:
    org.mule.module.apikit.exception.UnsupportedMediaTypeException
    at org.mule.module.apikit.HttpRestRequest.handleUnsupportedMediaType(HttpRestRequest.java:306)
    at org.mule.module.apikit.HttpRestRequest.negotiateInputRepresentation(HttpRestRequest.java:300)

**Environment**
Mule 3.8 runtime on Studio version 6.1.1

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have this for the GET request:

```
get:
      description: Get/Download list of all ACTIVE accounts in a given format (CSV/JSON) default is JSON
      body:
        application/json:
```

Remove body: application/json there's no need for it on the GET request. It will then allow you invoke the API without a Content-type.

Comment: added set-property in **api-main** flow as below.
This flow is RAML generated, so any alteration would have any side effects ??

With below changes, my requirement work

    `<flow name="api-main">
        <http:listener config-ref="api-httpListenerConfig" path="/api/*" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Property"  />
        <apikit:router config-ref="api-config" doc:name="APIkit Router" />
        <exception-strategy ref="api-apiKitGlobalExceptionMapping" doc:name="Reference Exception Strategy" />
    </flow>`

Answer (score 0):

I wish if it worked. 
Get the same exception. RAML after @ryan-carter suggestions

```
/{format}:
    is: [ genericErrorResponsesCompliant ]
    get:
      description: Get list of all ACTIVE accounts for a given country in a given format (CSV/JSON) default is JSON
      headers:
        Content-Type:
          default:
            '*/*'
      responses:    
        200: 
          body: 
            application/octet-stream:
```

Comment: any more changes to be done?

I do not want to pass the Content-type and wish to execute the request